# How to extract version from a single command line in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a product which has a command called `db2level` whose output is given below

[image]

I need to extract `8.1.1.64` out of it, so far i came up with,

`db2level | grep "DB2 v" | awk '{print$5}'`

which gave me an output `v8.1.1.64",`

Please help me to fetch `8.1.1.64`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db2level | grep "DB2 v" | awk '{print$5}' | sed 's/[^0-9\.]//g'
```

remove all but numbers and dot

Comment: Hey Thanks, Can you explain me what does is `sed` doing here?

Comment: sed is removing all but numbers 0-9 and dot \. remember /g at the end, that means "remove all occurrences".

Answer (score 3):

grep is enough to do that:

```
db2level| grep -oP '(?<="DB2 v)[\d.]+(?=", )'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just with awk:

```
db2level | awk -F '"' '$2 ~ /^DB2 v/ {print substr($2,6)}'
```

Answer (score 2):

sed is your friend for general extraction tasks:

```
db2level | sed -n -e 's/.*tokens are "DB2 v\([0-9.]*\)".*/\1/p'
```

The sed line does print no lines (the -n) but those where a replacement with the given regexp can happen. The .* at the beginning and the end of the line ensure that the whole line is matched.

Comment: I like this answer the best. It's only one process and avoids grep with `-P`.

Answer (score 2):

Try **grep** with `-o` option:

```
db2level | grep -E -o "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]\+[0-9]+"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `sed` solution

```
db2level | sed -n -e '/v[0-9]/{s/.*DB2 v//;s/".*//;p}'
```

This one desn't rely on the number being in a particular format, just in a particular place in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try s.th. like `db2level | grep "DB2 v" | cut -d'"' -f2 | cut -d'v' -f2`

cut splits the input in parts, seperated by delimiter -d and outputs field number -f

Comment: I like my answer because it doesn't involve sed or RegExps :)

Comment: then use `fgrep` or `grep -F`.

Comment: Isn't there a regexp in your answer?

Comment: even in your answer, you are indirectly using regexp. that's why i said to use a fixed pattern like this: grep -F or fgrep

Answer (score 1):

```
db2level | grep -o "v[0-9.]*" | tr -d v
```